# How to Extract stored procedures and functions in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, function, dependencies, procedure

I have a a stored function and it is referencing a table's column in its body.I want to get the information about the table and columns.How do I get it?same for a procedure also.

Answer (score 0):

`USE myDatabase;`

`SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure;`

`SHOW CREATE FUNCTION myFunction;`

Should give you the information about that StoredProcedure / fuction, including how it was built. From there you can see what tables / columns it references.

Comment: I got it previously.But I am using this in a program and I cant parse the whole function or procedure body to extract the table name.As the oracle provides 'all_dependency' table which gives everything needed in separate column I want something like that which will give me direct referenced table name.Hope you got the question or should I elaborate more?Same in terms of Views Also.